# Facebook Graph API can't like

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I would like to be able to like a Facebook status using the Graph API. I have successfully written a status update and a comment to a status update so it all seems to be perfectly set up. Still, I get an error when trying to like a status update.

This is the error I get:

```
Error details: {
    error =     {
        message = "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
}
```

This is my code:

```
NSString *postId = [data objectForKey:@"post_id"];
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", postId];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:request andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'd imagine you didn't include a valid app_id in your request.

Comment: Apparently I have to send a dictionary containing the application id as value to key `app_id`. `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1234567890", @"app_id", nil]` I thought that wouldn't be necessary as the app id is set when initializing `facebook`. Sorry, it was a stupid mistake. I'm not sure what the routine is here. Should you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, I've posted this as an answer now. Credit goes to Facebook, really, for the descriptive error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `app_id` in your request.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and the problem wasn't that my app_id was missing. I tried a bunch of different things without any luck then finally resolved the problem by revoking access for the iOS app in my general settings and then allowing them again.

I opened the app once in between this too, so I can't confirm whether flipping the switch on/off is enough.

I think the problem can arise when users upgrade their OS and username/password has to be reentered for FB/Twitter accounts. For whatever it messes with apps' individual access permissions.